# TableView not showing on button click in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am creating dropdown in iphone app i have place the button on top on that click tableview opens and hides but it does not show table view it

I have followed the tutorial from following link

http://iphone-rahulvarma.blogspot.com/2011/06/customized-drop-down-list-in-iphone.html

```
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblSimpleTable;
IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
IBOutlet UIImageView *i;
BOOL flag;
NSArray *arryData;


   }
   @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
   @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *tblSimpleTable;
   @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *i;
   @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *arryData;

  -(IBAction)btnClicked;





      arryData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",@"iPhone",@"iPod",@"MacBook",@"MacBook Pro",nil];
flag=1;
tblSimpleTable.hidden=YES;
btn.layer.cornerRadius=8;
tblSimpleTable.layer.cornerRadius=8;
```

Comment: tblSimpleTable.hidden=YES; ... hidden=NO . u hide the table.

Comment: yes when button is clicked it show table

Comment: @Chinttu can you help me out please why this is not showing table

Comment: Since you have followed tutorial code is gonna be ok I suppose, Have you connected `datasources` and `delegates` properly in .xib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this code: [NSNestedTable](https://github.com/serverdensity/ios-SDNestedTable)